# Send checkbox values from View to Action via View Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, checkbox

I wanna send checkboxes value from View to Action with viewmodel.

Can you help me ؟

I'm sorry about my terrible English

Comment: Please provide example code you have so far. Describing a specific issue is more helpful. Are you having problems posting the checkbox values to your controller? What is the view currently sending when you submit?

Comment: Hello @mr lemon did you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way to achieve your requirements

***View Model:***

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public List<Plans> plans { get; set; }
}

public class Plans
    {

        public int PlanId { get; set; }
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

***Controller When Load View Model:***

```
   public IActionResult LoadCheckBoxFromViewModel()
        {
            var plan = new List<Plans>()
            {
                new Plans(){ PlanName = "Plan A",PlanId =1, IsSelected= false},
                new Plans(){ PlanName = "Plan B",PlanId =2, IsSelected= false},
                new Plans(){ PlanName = "Plan C",PlanId =3, IsSelected= false},
                new Plans(){ PlanName = "Plan D",PlanId =4, IsSelected= false}

            };

            var model = new CheckBoxViewModel();
            model.plans = plan;
            return View(model);
        }
```

> ***Note:*** I have loaded the `checkbox` with few predefined value to check. If you need a single checkbox so you can simply customize it as per your requirement. In that case you don't need to loop through the `plan` checkbox list.

***View Of LoadCheckBoxFromViewModel Controller:***

```
@model CheckBoxViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LoadCheckBoxFromViewModel";
}

<h4>Load CheckBox From ViewModel</h4>
<h4>Submit value to Controller</h4>

<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetValueFromCheckBoxUsingViewModel", "StackOverFlow"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.plans.Count; i++)
    {

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.plans[i].IsSelected)
        <label>  @Model.plans[i].PlanName</label>


        @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.plans[i].PlanId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.plans[i].PlanName)
    }
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

***Controller When Submit Checkbox:***

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetValueFromCheckBoxUsingViewModel(CheckBoxViewModel checkBoxViewModel)
        {

            return View(checkBoxViewModel);
        }
```

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it would guide you through.